# onbeforeunload jquery & css styling handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am looking for commands to insert and modify the "onbeforeunload" javascript tag. I am looking primarily to style the buttons and to change the behavior of the button text. And some CSS overall to style everything would be nice too, but I am stuck.

There seems to be nowhere that clearly defines how to style the onbeforeunload pop up window. Help anyone?

Comment: That is completely impossible.

Answer (score 0):

onbeforeunload "pop-up" is native to the browser.

Comment: So no styling? No change of buttons, no nothing? I dont understand what you are saying, by just saying: native to browser. Ok what does that mean except that its native?

Comment: @JackHarris: It means that it isn't HTML.

Comment: Yes true, it means that. The million dollar question is however - can I edit it? Can I affect it? Can I do a javascript or some jquery to make it do what I want it to do? As in, I want to change its style.